# How to unable backend Customer Module for several users?

Tags: plugins, module, attributes, backend, shopware

I'm working with Shopware.

I've added a new attribute `"proxy"` to the `s_core_auth` table for each user in order to show the ability to get access to the Customer Module in the backend, so that if a user is not selected as `"proxy"` he/she won't be able to make changes in that module.

I need help to understand what I need to write in my plugin's code (maybe having only a Subscriber file.)

I'll be very grateful!

Answer (score 1):

Adding a custom column to the `s_core_auth` table is not a good idea. What you're trying to achieve can be done with **user groups** and **group rights**. From the Shopware [Documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20171001161256/http://en.community.shopware.com/User-administration_detail_804.html):

> With User administration you are able to create new users in the backend and control access rights to areas, modules and plugins in accordance with certain group policies that you define per ACL (Access Control List). Within the ACL you have the possibility to control precisely which user is able to perform which activity. Thus, it is possible to assign certain reader rights to an administration group without granting them authorization to edit or delete.

You can find instructions for User administration inside the [Documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20171001161256/http://en.community.shopware.com/User-administration_detail_804.html).

Comment: @ShushanikKostumyan Glad to help. If you think my answer solved your problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. :)